# Show Taxonomy with all terms in article url

Tags: path-aliases

i want to show http://example.com/category/subcategory-1/subcategory-2/title of article format for any article.

I have used Pathauto module but unable to configure as desired.

Comment: create a view of article node with contexual filter (nid from url) and set your desired path

Answer (score 0):

> Go to url- /admin/config/search/path/patterns/add.
>
> Select "Pattern type" from drop down.(Ex- Content.)
>
> Select "Content type" for those you want to configure the path.
>
> Provide a nice label to it.(recommended)

Rest select the available tokens for the content type that you can use from "Browse available tokens" link.

Refer to the attached screen shot.

[image]

Comment: I have configured same but not reflecting any changes on frondend..

Comment: http://prntscr.com/disi63  you can check screenshot as i have used available tokens for article and default path

Comment: I think you need to edit the node and save it to reflect the changes on frontend.

Comment: or create a new node of article content type to see the changes

Comment: since i have already approx 4000 articles and listings there... i want to make changes in all automatically as we required

Comment: Hope you got your solution.

Comment: you can also programmatically load all the nodes related to article content type using **EntityQuery** and can make changes and save them to reflect the changes to each node.